# Is tattoing alowed in hinduism?

Tags: practice, customs

I love tattoing and I am a devotee of lord krishna. I think whether tattoing god's name on body is a sin as I am a girl? Does hinduism allow tattoing? Is there any notes about tattoing in puranas?

Comment: Tattoos are modern concept and they are not mentioned in Puranas or Hindu literature.

Comment: Am I free to tatto then..

Comment: Well Tattoing gods name or Figure is Objectionable, which part of your body you want to tatto it to? I think Urdhwapundra(Namam) is sort of a tatto or spiritual label, so tattoing is present and allowed in hinduism. Since a human body is made pure by urdhwapundra it is okay but in your case body tatto is permanent and body is not pure permanently so its better that you avoid the tattoing god's name.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18281/is-that-ethically-correct-if-non-vegetarian-to-tattoo-gods-pray-or-image-on-for

Comment: No @The Destroyer, tattooing is not a modern things but surely Hinduism is much older...

Comment: Have a look at this. Tattooing is at least 4000BC old.  http://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/oldest-tattoo-ever-found-marks-on-iceman-otzi-proved-to-be-first-known-body-art-a6777476.html

Comment: I may not have very much knowledge in Hinduism but I think that if a tattoo on your body makes you more devoted then it should be welcomed @Gayathri.

Comment: Well, I think that tattooing is not prohibited in Hinduism. Hindus have always been fond of Beautification and women are said to color their feet with Lac(red dye) and mehndi. And we all know the Lord of Beauty the Supreme soul The Inconceivable and the most Beloved Lord Narayana is called ShringaaraNayaka. So Tattooing is also beautification. BUT--

Comment: As pointed by everybody, one must not at all use God and God related stuff for Beautification purposes. I do not know of scriptural reference, but a well renowned and Genuine Guruji, whose program comes on TV, says- "Never at all one must wear Tabijas(pendents with God photo, or God form, or Om, or mantra et cetera). God is placed in heart and not made for hanging in our neck or hands as pendents. By doing this, God becomes 'Kupita'(wrathful or irritated). So one must not wear God on body."

Comment: He also stated- "People often out of devotion wear God on body as pendents or other ornaments, but it makes God angry. So people should avoid it." And so we do can deduct that same applies for Tattooing God on body. Also note- the Guru is a Genuine one, and he does not keep on only speaking philosophies or morals. He has greatly mastered astrology and many have benefitted. I am not mentioning His name for identity issues and it seems awkward to advertise some Guru's name.

Comment: I have many ISKCONite friends who sport Jagannath tattoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puranas do not speak about tattoos. 
Tattoing of God's name on body should not be done. In vaishnava Brahmin tradition we have to emboss the shanku and chakra on the shoulders after upanayanam, not God's name. It has to be given due respect.
The human body will be buried or lit into flames after the atma separates from it. If you tattoo God's name this will also go into the mud or consigned to flames which is not acceptable. Lord Krishna the sarveswaran should not be treated like this. He is the preserver and he is Omni-present. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Can I tatoo peacock feather in my rigth hand..?? @Parthasarathy Raghavan

Comment: @Gayatri--   Peacock is the vaganam of Lord Subramanya.Lord Krishna [Your favourite God] has peacock feather on the head. You can tattoo peacock feather as mentioned in the question. I think there will be no harm in it.

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable comment @Parthasarathy Raghavan

Comment: Welcome  and hope your question is clarified to the fullest extent.

Comment: " In Brahmin tradition we have to emboss the shanku and chakra on the shoulders " - this is applicable only to vaishnavas.

Comment: @moonstar2001. Yes, it is applicable to Vaishnavas. I think that your comment is also the reason of the edit. You can also add it in the edit reason  next time you make an edit.

Comment: "If you tattoo God's name this will also go into the mud or consigned to flames which is not acceptable" Really, how did you come to this conclusion?