# Is that ethically correct if non-vegetarian to Tattoo god's pray or image on forearm

Tags: shiva, gods, mantras

I want to tattoo the loard shiva's pray like the image below.

[image]

My question is that ethical that to tattoo as I'm non-vegetarian.

Comment: Being non-vegetarian is not why it is wrong.  Reducing mantras to tattoos is disrespectful and can be harmful.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Thanks for response could you please in what manner it would be `disrespectful and can be harmful` ,  So I can understand it in better sense

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58679/discussion-on-question-by-n-j-is-that-ethically-correct-if-non-vegetarian-to-tat).

Comment: You can tattoo an image of Lord SHiva instead of that mantra. I think that will be better. Also being a non vegetarian or not being one does not matter. Because in both those cases Lord Shiva still exists in you & in ur heart. I mean does he cease  to exist ((in ur heart) if u are eating non-veg ? NO of course.

Comment: Well One must not wear tattoos and Taabijs(the pendent with god photo or god shape, om, mantra et cetera) and not wear and use any God related stuff for "beautification and adorning of body parts". I heard from a well renowned and genuine Guru that- ' one must not use God and God related stuff for adorning. God has place in heart and not in our necks, waist, t-shirts, pendents, bracelet et cetera. This makes the God 'Kupita'(meaning wrathful). And so it is not to be done'. I am not mentioning His(Guruji's) name for identity issues